# Reading the decimal value of little endian in PHP

Tags: php

I'm reading 6 bytes in little endian from a binary file using

```
$data = fread($fp, 6);
unpack("V", $data);
```

The result is 1152664389 and in HEX it is 0x44B44345

Now this result is in little endian and has a decimal number. In Delphi, I was able to get the decimal number using this function:

```
var
myint:integer;
s:single;
begin
myint:= 1152664389; // same as myint:= $44B44345;
s:= PSingle(@myint)^;
```

and output of s is 1442.102.. This is exactly the number im looking for...

I searched for a way to do it in PHP but I just got lost.

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: How comes that the decimal number is smaller than the hex number? 10 decimal digits compared to 12 hex digits - these will never be the same value. The decimal number converted to hex is the last 8 digits: 0x44B44345. Can you fix your numbers and then write down exactly what you want to get as the result.

Comment: Sven, I'm sorry, yes you're right. The hex value is 0x44B44345. I'll correct it in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was a bit confused. I wanted to actually retrieve a little endian number from a binary file then convert it to float.

So my steps were:

1) Read bytes and unpack using $number = unpack("V", $data);
2) Convert $number to decimal using dechex.
3) Then use the following function to convert hex to float:

```
function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
$v = hexdec($strHex);
$x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
$exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23);
}
```

Thanks again.